# Removing a rear wheel of a town bike

Tags: road-bike, internally-geared-hub, rear-wheel

I'm a beginner in repairing bicycles. I have quite an old town bike. I'm trying to change the tires. I have trouble in taking out the back wheel. As you can see in the picture, there is a small piece of chain connected into the hub shell.

I've checked for a small clasp or small screws to remove it but it doesn't seem to have any. Does anyone know how to remove this? Or am I doing something wrong? Any help is appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This picture shows a slightly better angle. You need to first loosen the lock nut slightly, then spin the adjuster barrel until it unscrews right off the threaded rod on the chain. When you re-assemble you reverse that, and have to [re-adjust the tension so that it shifts properly](http://oldbikeblog.blogspot.com.au/2008/07/how-to-adjust-sturmey-archer-three.html).

[image: gear adjustment on three speed hub]

Answer (score 3):

To the last question, a far better order of doing things would have been to disconnect the shifting cable first. The knurled part at the end of cable rotates on the threaded piece at the end of the chain, visible through the hole in the wheel nut. Rotate it to disconnect the cable.

Comment: Thanks alot for the advise @ojs. Actually I didn't look properly at the rear wheel. Just thought I could unscrew the nuts and get it done. It was my bad.